Homomorphisms under localization
I have the following Lemma in my course:

Assume $M$ is a finitely presented $A$-module, $S \subset A$ is a multiplicative set. Then there exists a natural isomorphism of $S^{-1}A$ modules:
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}M,S^{-1}N) \simeq S^{-1}\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N) $$

The proof states that this is a direct consequence of the fact that $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N) \mapsto S^{-1}f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}M,S^{-1}N)$ is an isomorphism in the finitely presented case.
I've heard that by taking the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for an appropriate $S \subset \mathbb{Z}$ one can find a counter-example to the (non-finite) case.
However, I've unable to reach anything meaningful. My current approach goes as follows:
It seems to me that we have:

As a $\mathbb{Z}$ homomorphism, $f$ is uniquely determined by $f(1/q)$ for $q$ prime numbers.
As a $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ homomorphism, $S^{-1}f$ is determined by $S^{-1}f\left(\frac{(a/q)}{s}\right) = \frac{f(a/q)}{s} = \frac{a}{s}f(1/q)$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}, s\in S$ and $q$ prime. This also means that $S^{-1}f$ is determined (up to equivalence) by the $f(1/q)$ for $q$ prime.

By considering $S := \mathbb{Z}\setminus(p)$ for $p$ prime and playing with the values of a certain function on $1/p$ and $1/q$, we could contradict that the kernel must be the trivial function.
For example, we have  $f(1) = 0 = \frac{q f(1/q)}{s}$, $f(1) = 0 = \frac{p f(1/p)}{s} = \frac{p}{s} f(1/p)$. And perhaps by setting $f(1/q) = 1/q$ and $f(1/p) =0$, we can choose $s=q$ and obtain $S^{-1}f = 0$ everywhere, but $f(1/q) = 1/q \neq 0$. But I feel as if this might be wrong, ie. I'm misunderstanding the concepts at play.
An alternative approach I tried was attempting to show that. This hasn't been successful:
If $f \mapsto S^{-1}f$ is indeed an isomorphism, then $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ would be finitely generated.

Here’s a different way to get a counterexample. We want $A$-modules $M$ and $N$ such that the natural map
$$ S^{-1}\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}M,S^{-1}N) $$
is not an isomorphism.
We take $A=\mathbb Z$. As we don’t want $M$ to be finitely generated we take $M=\mathbb Z^{(I)}$ for some infinite set $I$, and $N=\mathbb Z$. We take $S=\mathbb Z-\{0\}$, so that $S^{-1}\mathbb Z=\mathbb Q$. Now,
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(M,N) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z^{(I)},\mathbb Z) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)^I = \mathbb Z^I. $$
Similarly, since tensoring commutes with taking direct sums, we have $S^{-1}M=\mathbb Q^{(I)}$ and $S^{-1}N=\mathbb Q$, so that
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_{S^{-1}\mathbb Z}(S^{-1}M,S^{-1}N) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Q}(\mathbb Q^{(I)},\mathbb Q) = \mathbb Q^I. $$
The question then becomes: is the natural map
$$ \mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z^I \to \mathbb Q^I $$
an isomorphism? The answer is no, and this is fairly standard. Any element $x=(x_i)$ on the left has bounded denominators, so $dx\in\mathbb Z^I$ for some integer $d$. On the other hand, we can take an unbounded sequence $n_i$ of positive integers and take the element $(1/n_i)$ on the right.
